# @JmsListener reads messages from queue only on ActiveMQ restart

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have a multi module java application each module is a spring boot application.
One module runs activemq instance programmatically.
Other 3 modules connect on that activemq and send/receive messages. 
I got this messaging work but when I was trying something to fix in my consumer module then suddenly the other modules stop connecting to the activemq...
Below are the brief descriptors of modules

activemq program,

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
broker.start()
```

and the module connects with methods annotated with @JmsListener.

Now the producer module sends messages to queue however the listener module don't read messages instantly from queue but reads only if I restart the activemq. 
On restart of activemq, the log says

o.a.a.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase       : Recovering from the journal ...
o.a.a.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase       : Recovery replayed 1 operations from the journal in 0.014 seconds.

and on start of activemq I get below WARN messages in log

.a.a.b.TransportConnection.Transport    : Transport onnection to: tcp://192.168.3.1:27888 failed: java.io.EOFException

o.a.a.b.TransportConnection.Transport    : Transport Connection to: tcp://192.168.3.1:27889 failed: java.io.EOFException

o.a.a.b.TransportConnection.Transport    : Transport Connection to: tcp://192.168.3.1:27890 failed: java.io.EOFException

o.a.a.b.TransportConnection.Transport    : Transport Connection to: tcp://192.168.3.1:27891 failed: java.io.EOFException

o.a.a.b.TransportConnection.Transport    : Transport Connection to: tcp://192.168.3.1:27892 failed: java.io.EOFException

Any help/info is appreciated..

Comment: have you changed some dependencies ? all AMQ clients have the same versions ?

Comment: Yes, All AMQ client has the same version and no change in any dependency.